# Significance of Peter being nude in Forgetting Sarah Marshall

Tags: character, analysis, forgetting-sarah-marshall

At the beginning of [Forgetting Sarah Marshall](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800039/?ref_=nv_sr_1), Peter gets dumped by Sarah while being completely nude. And then, at the end of the film, he and Rachel seem to start a relationship, with Peter being completely nude again.

Other than the surprise factor, and the humor of it, is there a deeper meaning to Peter being naked when ending and beginning his relationships?

Comment: probably to sell more tickets

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It [happened to Jason Segel in real life](https://www.npr.org/2015/08/14/432162018/jason-segel-on-breakups-bromances-and-freaks-and-geeks), as he told Terry Gross for NPR's *Fresh Air*:

> SEGEL: That was taken from the pages of real life. **I once got dumped
>   while I was naked, but she asked me to put clothes on during this real
>   breakup, my real-life breakup, and as opposed to in the movie when I
>   say no, I did go to put clothes o**n. So she waited for me while I went
>   back into my room to get dressed. Let me just tell you, Terry.
>
> GROSS: Yeah?
>
> SEGEL: Picking out an outfit for the second half of a breakup is like
>   the hardest outfit you'll ever pick out in your life.
>
> (LAUGHTER)
>
> SEGEL: I came out - I came out in a blue button-up shirt and khaki
>   pants, like I was going to private school.
>
> (LAUGHTER)
>
> GROSS: So did it seem funny to you at the time, or was it just in
>   retrospect that - these things take on…
>
> SEGEL: You know what? **I think maybe this is the mind of a writer, I
>   guess. But it was - while this breakup is happening, which was
>   probably the most significant moment of my life to date, you know,
>   when that happened, and I'm naked, and the whole time I'm thinking
>   this is really, really funny. I'm going to use this in a movie
>   someday.** And slowly her voice became like the teacher from Charlie
>   Brown, you know, just wha-wha-wha, wha-wha-wha (ph), while I was
>   slowly constructing the scene in my mind.

He also [told the *LA Times*](http://www.latimes.com/entertainment/envelope/cotown/la-et-frontal16apr16-story.html):

> Segel also wrote the film's script, basing the scene on a real-life
>   naked breakup of his own. Still, the actor-writer contemplated
>   inequalities between male and female film nudity before putting his
>   family jewels on display.
>
> "When a woman does nudity in a movie, men immediately switch into a
>   sexual mode," Segel said. "For women, from what I understand, it's not
>   like that. They see a naked, out-of-shape man crying and **it's funny --
>   something weird, disturbing and disgusting we can all laugh at.**"

In that same article, Judd Apatow sees the scene as part of a larger "movement":

> To hear him tell it, Apatow -- the comedy rainmaker behind *"The
>   40-Year-Old Virgin*" who has shown a Midas touch producing such jocular
>   male-skewing comedies as "*Knocked Up*," "*Talladega Nights: The Ballad
>   of Ricky Bobby*" and "*Anchorman: The Legend of Ron Burgundy*" -- **has
>   made it a sort of personal mission to up the on-screen male member
>   quotient.**
>
> **Call it a crusade to break down one of moviedom's last taboos**. In the
>   2007 faux musical biopic he produced, "*Walk Hard: The Dewey Cox
>   Story*," Apatow positioned a penis behind the film's star John C.
>   Reilly's head during an orgy scene. The upshot: Some 20 audience
>   members reportedly stormed out of a test screening in disgust. As
>   well, the closing credits for another film Apatow produced, the teen
>   comedy "*Superbad*," feature a hilarious illustrated montage of male
>   sexual organs.
>
> **"America fears the penis, and that's something I'm going to help them
>   get over," Apatow is quoted as having said in a *World Entertainment
>   News Service* story in December. "I'm gonna get a penis in every movie
>   I do from now on. . . . It really makes me laugh in this day and age,
>   with how psychotic our world is, that anyone is troubled by seeing any
>   part of the human body."**